# Databricks error when trying to load a module using apache spark

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, databricks

I'm using a notebook within Databricks. The notebook is set up with python 3 if that helps. Everything is working fine and I can extract data from Azure Storage. However when I run:

`import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType`

I get the error message

`ImportError: No module named 'org'`

Does anyone know how I would go about fixing this? Is this something to do with the notebook being in python?

I've only just started using Databricks today so apologies if this is a silly question - I couldn't find anything online that helped.

I did try to run `import org.py.spark.sql.types.StructType` but that didn't work either.

Thanks

Comment: That did work thank you. I now have a different error message though which says 
'NameError: name 'List' is not defined'. Any ideas?

Comment: Same basic idea - google it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to import scala libraries in a Python notebook.  You need to either change to using a Scala notebook, or use the Pyspark equivalents.

Like:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
```